# Add/Update list of K,V pair to empty declared map = List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have and empty map, **Map optionSelection = {};**

And on every button click I want to add list of `K,V` pair map to **optionSelection** map.

**Format in which I want to add Map.**

```
{
   "quiz_id": selectedOption,
   "ques_id": questionId,
   "user_ans_id": selectedOption,
}
```

In above Key and Value pair, in **"ques_id": questionId** -> **questionId** will be unique, So I want to check if the value already exist, if ***YES*** then I want to update the `"user_ans_id": selectedOption` value or else I want to add new list of `K,V` pair.

Below is the code I tried

```
final quesExist = optionSelection.containsValue(questionId);

if (quesExist) {
  optionSelection.putIfAbsent(
    "ques_id",
    () => optionSelection.addAll(
      {
        "quiz_id": selectedOption,
        "ques_id": questionId,
        "user_ans_id": selectedOption,
      },
    ),
  );
} else {
  optionSelection.addAll(
    {
      "quiz_id": selectedOption,
      "ques_id": questionId,
      "user_ans_id": selectedOption,
    },
  );
}
```

Hope I was able to explain my issue, Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you want to update use `update` method, not `putIfAbsent`

Comment: Hi @pskink, I want to update the value of specific `Key` if specific value exist in that particular **key**, and add new `K,V pair` if does not exist.

Comment: Hi @pskink, thank you for the idea, but I want to do the same with `Set<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>` map as I explained in the post.

Comment: so what is `optionSelection` then? is it a `Map` or `Set`?

Comment: Hi @pskink, I apologise I am new to **Dart programming**, I am developing a Quiz app, in which each quiz has 3 or 4 RadioListTile and the solution is single choice based, So I want to create `List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>` which can contain multiple Map, that I can push it to server.

`{
      "quiz_id": selectedOption,
      "ques_id": questionId,
      "user_ans_id": selectedOption,
    }`

and f the **questionId** don't exit then add new pair of Map or if the **questionId** exist in `List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>` then update the `selectedOption`

Answer (score 1):

after a week of struggle and many tweaks in code, here is the final solution for above query.

```
    // Declared empty List<Map>
    List<Map> optionSelection = [];

    // Variable to store bool value, if the question id exist
    var questionExist;

    // Feed the map in below form
    Map<String, dynamic> userSelection = {
      "quiz_id": widget.quizId,
      "ques_id": questionId,
      "user_ans_id": selectedOption,
    };

    // Check if the Ques Id Exist in List<Map> optionSelection
    questionExist = optionSelection.any((map) => map.containsValue(questionId));

    // Check using if else condition, if Ques Id exist, then run the forLoop,
    // to iterate in List<Map>, else add a new Set of Map to the List<Map>
    if (questionExist == true) {
      print("If triggered");
      for (var map in optionSelection) {
        if (map.containsValue(questionId)) {
          map.update("user_ans_id", (dynamic val) => selectedOption);
        }
      }
    } else {
      print("Else triggered");
      optionSelection.add(userSelection);
    }
```