# how to select ,deselect and disable items?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, maps, flutter-card, flutter-radiobutton

I have cards in my app and each card has 4 items with grey color, if the item is selected then its color change to blue and the same item in other cards should disable am unable to do that using maps collection. So I have items like IT, DEV, TEST, HR if IT is selected in any one of the cards then the remaining IT items in the remaining cards should disable.
I will attach the screenshots of the app and code below. Anyone can help me, please. Thanks in Advance.[image: initial screen]
[image: after adding maximum 4 cards]

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CardWithTextformfield(),
    );
  }
}

class CardWithTextformfield extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardWithTextformfield({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CardWithTextformfieldState createState() => _CardWithTextformfieldState();
}

class _CardWithTextformfieldState extends State<CardWithTextformfield> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  var name =<TextEditingController>[];
  var id =<TextEditingController>[];

  var addCard =1;

  void incrementcard(){
    setState(() {
      if(addCard >=4){
        return;
      }
      addCard++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Card with TextformField'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: incrementcard,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child:ListView.builder(
          itemCount: addCard,
            itemBuilder: (context,index){
            return cardslist(index);
            }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget cardslist(int index){
    if(name.length <= index){
      name.add(TextEditingController());
      id.add(TextEditingController());
    }
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Text('Team Name: ')),
                Expanded(child: TextFormField(
                  controller: name[index],
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Team Name'),
                ),),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Text('Team Id: '),),
                Expanded(child: TextFormField(
                  controller: id[index],
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Team Id'),
                ),),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 50,height: 50,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('IT'),),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 50,height: 50,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('DEV'),),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 50,height: 50,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('TEST'),),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 50,height: 50,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('HR'),),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

as what I understood is that, you want to compare the value from values inside **`map`**

Declare a global -> bool variable `(final bool isSelected = false)`

- Store the value in a **`variable`**, which you want to compare
- Use forLoop to iterate the values in map
- Check if the value exist, set **`isSelected = true`**
- Use **`isSelected`** to set the color

  ```
           GestureDetector(
             child: Container(
               width: 50,height: 50,
               margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                 color: isSelected == true ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
               ),
               child: Center(child: Text('HR'),),
             ),
           ),
  ```

Please check the post once for Map iteration - [Add/Update list of K,V pair to empty declared map = List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68813290/add-update-list-of-k-v-pair-to-empty-declared-map-listmapdynamic-dynamic/68909322#68909322)

Hope it solves the issue

Comment: Thanks, @indrajeet but My problem is not only with color but also implementing logic. So, if an item is selected in one card then the items in the remaining cards should disable(not selectable, change to color light white). grey color indicates selectable, blue indicates selected and light white indicates not selectable. Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Hi, you can tell me, how are you defining which item to select ?

Comment: Hey, @indrajeet anyway other than a map collection to solve the issue?

Comment: Hi @shanmkha did you got the solution, If not then please explain me `how are you defining which item to select` ?

Comment: Hey @indrajeet I didn't got the solution and I Am not working on this particular